# Running A Container On GCE

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-compute-engine

Having a hell of a time getting a container to run on Google Cloud Engine. I have set up a simple API in Go and can't seem to expose it to the work using GCE. I have a network setup and an external IP, I have firewall rules exposing 80 and 443. I allow http and https on my GCE instance. My Dockerfile exposes 80 and 443. I can build and run locally. When I push the container to my GCE VM it runs and build a container and its running but when I look at the container the ports are blank. I have confirmed it is attached to the host network so it should be using the VM's ports (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#publishing_container_ports). This should attach to the subnets ip address and the VM host stack exposing the ports. I feel like I am missing a simple config in the GCE. Anyone else run into this issue?

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY service1 ./

RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o /service1

EXPOSE 80/TCP
EXPOSE 443/TCP

CMD ["/service1"]
```

Comment: what is the full command you're using to run the container?

Comment: I am not running any command. With GCE it runs the container when installed/updated onto the VM.  -p is not supported on GCE images.
"Container ports have a one-to-one mapping to the host VM ports. For example, a container port 80 maps to the host VM port 80. Compute Engine does not support the port publishing (-p) flag, and you do not have to specify it for the mapping to work."

Comment: Ohh I see, you're running the container directly using. My best guess is that the container is being terminated to it would be a good idea you ssh in the VM and run the container manually and check any logs

Comment: yeah its up and running when I SSH in and the only log I get is Defaulting to 8080